# Send smtp gmail email ''Failure sending mail''

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am trying to send email in c# using gmail smtp server but it giving me an error `Failure sending mail``.

Everything is fine username and password. What wrong with this code that can cause this error?

```
 var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypassword"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I have had this before with gmail, you need to adjust your account security settings and then it will give you a warning saying youre less secure, but then youll be able to send email again.  You'll most likely and annoyingly have to change your password too

Comment: @SimonPrice what must I adjust or change so that my username can allow me to send smtp email?

Comment: @MuziwenhlanhlaDlamini What is the inner exception?

Comment: @user1666620 Inner Exception is `Unable to connect to the remote server` but username and password is correct.

Comment: @MuziwenhlanhlaDlamini That indicates that it isn't the login credential at fault, but rather a connection error. Is the computer the application running on connected to the internet? Is there a firewall blocking the application? Is there a router port which needs to be opened? Also, can you post the full inner exception?

Comment: @user1666620 full Inner Exception is saying `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.233.184.109:465`

Comment: @MuziwenhlanhlaDlamini why is port 465 listed there? You should be using port 587.

Comment: @SimonPrice thanks guys it worked I went my account setting and enable `less secure` now it working thank you very much.

Comment: @user1666620 thanks guys it worked I went my account setting and enable `less secure` now it working thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will more helpfull to you
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en